# Unable to post files to Telegram from pycharm

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I searched google Bard and ChatGPT and found the above code.
I am trying to send files from my directory To telegram to my channel
It's is showing the below error.

Below configuration:
Windows 11 OS and pycharm as the IDE.
Installed selenium and telegram in the pycharm addon

My code:-

```
Import os
From telegram import Bot
bot=Bot(token="xxxxxx")

#Replace'YOUR_TELEGRAM_TOKEN'withyouractualTelegrambottoken
TOKEN='xxxx'

#Replace'YOUR_CHAT_ID'withyouractualTelegramchatID
CHAT_ID='xxxx'

#Directorypathcontainingthefilestoupload
DIRECTORY_PATH='E:\\upload\\2017'

defupload_files_to_telegram():
bot=Bot(token=TOKEN)
forfilenameinos.listdir(DIRECTORY_PATH):
file_path=os.path.join(DIRECTORY_PATH,filename)
ifos.path.isfile(file_path):
withopen(file_path,'rb')asfile:
bot.send_document(chat_id=CHAT_ID,document=file)
print(f"Uploaded{filename}successfully.")
```

Error Message:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\vss coding\Dayscoding100\venv\telegramupload.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram import Bot
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot' from 'telegram' (E:\vss coding\Dayscoding100\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\__init__.py)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you installed the PyPI project called [`telegram`](https://pypi.org/project/telegram/) instead of installing the PyPI project called [`python-telegram-bot`](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/). Both provide a package called `telegram`, but the former doesn't contain any functionality. See also [this PTB FAQ entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-am-i-getting-importerror-cannot-import-name-xy-from-telegram).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telgeram-bot`.

Comment: hi, So what i need to change to work properly? please guide me.

Comment: You need to read the linked FAQ entry and follow the instructions in there.